iOS18 WKWebview evaluateJavaScript crash in multiple thread - BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBPLATFORM: Trying to recursively lock an os_unfair_lock
After upgrade to iOS18, my iPhone app keeps crash with the following error:
libsystem_platform.dylib`_os_unfair_lock_recursive_abort:
    0x21852b0a4 <+0>:  mov    w8, w0
    0x21852b0a8 <+4>:  stp    x20, x21, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x21852b0ac <+8>:  adrp   x20, 0
    0x21852b0b0 <+12>: add    x20, x20, #0x7f2          ; "BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBPLATFORM: Trying to recursively lock an os_unfair_lock"
    0x21852b0b4 <+16>: adrp   x21, 352637
    0x21852b0b8 <+20>: add    x21, x21, #0x1c0          ; gCRAnnotations
    0x21852b0bc <+24>: str    x20, [x21, #0x8]
    0x21852b0c0 <+28>: str    x8, [x21, #0x38]
    0x21852b0c4 <+32>: ldp    x20, x21, [sp], #0x10
->  0x21852b0c8 <+36>: brk    #0x1


My app opens ~10 web pages at the same time by using WKWebview. Once the page is loaded, I use evaluateJavaScript to get the page html content. Then I use kanna to parse the html data.
The code likes:
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()", completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
                if (webView.url == nil)  {
                    return
                }
                //use kanna to parse the result

      })
}

After the debug, it seems that it will work OK if number of web pages being loaded concurrently is 2 or 3.  If I load 10 different web pages at the same time, the app will crash with the error:
BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBPLATFORM: Trying to recursively lock an os_unfair_lock
The same code has worked well in iOS17 or earlier.
I have tried the following approach:

put evaluateJavaScript in main thread
use lock/unlock before evaluateJavaScript

None of them worked in iOS18.
I would expect that the same codes should work as before.
Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.
